# "Sending the email to the following server failed : webmail.company.com:465"

Tags: java, smtp

I use this code to send email

```
 Email email = new SimpleEmail();
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setHostName("webmail.company.com");
            email.setSmtpPort(587);

            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username@company.com", "*****"));
            email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
            try {
                email.setFrom("username@company.com");

                email.setSubject("TestMail");

                email.setMsg("Hi "+receiver.getSex()+" "+receiver.getName()+" "+editorBean.getValue());

                email.addTo(receiver.getEmail());
                email.send();
            } catch (EmailException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PersonBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                result += "exptions :" + ex.getMessage();
                return result;
            }
```

and I think that smtp port is not changing 
"Sending the email to the following server failed : webmail.company.com:465"
what is the problem ?

Comment: Post the complete StackTrace here

Comment: webmail.company.com does not seem to be responding on port 465, is it supposed to? Does it work with an ordinary mail client?

Comment: I think either your mailserver or credentials are incorrect. Nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`setSslSmtpPort(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#setSslSmtpPort%28java.lang.String%29) rather than `setSmtpPort(int)` because you're connecting using SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your IP is black listed. there are some cases where you need to explicitly

white list your ip before connecting to smtp.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:

Change your settings in gmail account to allow less secure apps.
Go to https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and turn on **Access for less secure apps**

Step2:

In my case Avast Antivirus was causing the exception to be thrown when I was trying to send the email.

Avast shields control -> Disable for 10 minutes

(or)

Open Avast User Interface -> Settings -> Components -> MailShield(Customize) -> MainSettings - Uncheck the option 'Scan outbound mail (SMTP)'